# ドラッグ＆ドロップで移動したオブジェクトを保存するには？

Tags: python, python3, pyqt5

[Pyqt5 draggable QPushButton - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116811/pyqt5-draggable-qpushbutton)

上記を見てボタンやテキストボックス、画像等をドラッグ＆ドロップで移動可能にできたのですが、移動したオブジェクト情報（位置やテキスト内容）の保存／読み込みはどうすれば行えるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html)を使う方法が手ごろではないでしょうか。

**サンプルコード**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QPoint, QSize, Qt

class myApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myApp, self).__init__()

    def initUI(self):
        self.settings = QSettings("my_settings.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)

        self.button = self.findChild(DragButton)
        self.edit = self.findChild(QLineEdit)

        # 設定ファイルからボタンの位置とテキストを書き出す(なければ第二引数の既定値を使う)
        self.button.move(self.settings.value("button_pos", QPoint(0, 50)))
        self.edit.setText(self.settings.value("edit_text", "Hello World!"))

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        # 設定ファイルにボタンの位置とテキストを書き出す
        self.settings.setValue("button_pos", self.button.pos())
        self.settings.setValue("edit_text", self.edit.text())

        e.accept()

class DragButton(QPushButton):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.__mousePressPos = None
        self.__mouseMovePos = None
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.__mousePressPos = event.globalPos()
            self.__mouseMovePos = event.globalPos()

        super(DragButton, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # adjust offset from clicked point to origin of widget
            currPos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
            globalPos = event.globalPos()
            diff = globalPos - self.__mouseMovePos
            newPos = self.mapFromGlobal(currPos + diff)
            self.move(newPos)

            self.__mouseMovePos = globalPos

        super(DragButton, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.__mousePressPos is not None:
            moved = event.globalPos() - self.__mousePressPos 
            if moved.manhattanLength() > 3:
                event.ignore()

        super(DragButton, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

def clicked():
    print ("click as normal!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w   = myApp()
    w.resize(800,600)

    button = DragButton("Drag", w)
    button.clicked.connect(clicked)

    edit = QLineEdit(w)

    w.initUI() # 設定ファイル読み出し
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**参考にした本家SOの質問**

[How to remember last geometry of PyQt application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33869721)
[QSettings(): How to save to current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7962292)

Comment: 有難うございます。複数のボタンやテキストの情報を保存するにはどうすべきでしょうか？
一部を複製しただけでは同じ情報が保存されてしまいます。
classを複製すれば思うような動作にはなったのですが…